# Change h2 tag to h1 tag

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to change the product names on all product pages from h2 to h1

I would like to change this somehow to h1 with custom code.

```
<h2 itemprop="name" class="product_title likeh2">Aspen Ágykeret Bársony Sötétzöld 160 cm</h2>
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do you need some javascript code to change h2 elements to h1 elements? Or CSS to change the look of h2 to h1, or?

Comment: Please describe more what you actually want to achieve

Comment: There are no h1 tags on the product pages, just h2. And I would like to change the h2 tag to h1 in order to improve seo. But I cant edit the html all i can do is to manipulate it with javascript for rg.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Since you could do search-and-replace on the HTML to change h2 to h1, and are pretty obviously choosing not to do that, what special requirements do you have? Do you need to (or think you need to) do this using JavaScript in the client? Do you want to tranform h2 to h1 on the server side, as the HTML is sent to the client? Would just changing the CSS for h2 to look like h1 suffice?

Comment: If the goal is SEO, you need to change h2 to h1 *before* the page is sent to the client. You can't count on a search engine analyzing your code in the way it will appear *after* some bit of JavaScript code transforms the HTML. This will require server-side processing.

Comment: Hello guys. Thanks, it worked out pretty well. Thank you for your kind cooperation

Answer (score 2):

You could to something like this:

```
//select all h2 elements
document.querySelectorAll('h2').forEach( element => {
  //create new h1 element
  const newElement = document.createElement('h1');

  //set the inner html to the original h2 element 
  newElement.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;

  //take all attributes from original element and assign them to the new one
  Array.from(element.attributes).forEach( attr => {
    newElement.setAttribute(attr.nodeName, attr.nodeValue)
  })

  //replace the node in the dom
  element.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, element);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way to do it. It will depend on browser support for outerHTML, but that's looking pretty good nowadays: https://caniuse.com/#search=outerHTML

`querySelectorAll` is used rather than `getElementsByTagName` because the array of elements does not change even as the elements change. When you actually update the element within that array, it uses the reference to update the actual element, but it doesn't change within the array. That way we can continue looping through and altering all `<h2>` tags on the document, whereas the live list returned by `getElementsByTagName` would lose elements each time an `h2` tag is converted to an `h1`.

```js
const hTwos = document.querySelectorAll('h2');

for (let i = 0; i < hTwos.length; i++) {
  hTwos[i].outerHTML = hTwos[i].outerHTML.replace(/h2/g,"h1");
};
```

```html
<h2>Product 1</h2>
<h2>Product 2</h2>
```

Comment: Beware this will replace _any_ occurrence of "h2" present in the outerHTML, attribute names and values included. It may work in this particular case, but running the same logic on an `<i>` element would turn `<i id="icon"></i>` into `<h1 h1d="h1con"></h1>`. Also, the general idea of stringifying and replacing HTML just seems very hacky to me...